# Why is this not a relevant question for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, closed-questions

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [How to connect to AWS RDS on a private subnet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78207800/how-to-connect-to-aws-rds-on-a-private-subnet)

The moderator just closed this question. I am not offended but it is so weird that I have to ask here. As I also said in the comment in my question, the most relevant and most useful answers to AWS questions actually appear on Stack Overflow. How is that possible if only programming questions should be on this site? For example just search on Google: how to connect to EC2 on private subnet. First link (after AWS) is Stack Overflow with many comments, answers and upvotes.

Comment: There are thousands of questions asked every single day. Many that should be closed slip through because of the sheer volume.  Just because another question that should have been closed did not get closed does not mean yours should stay open.  Your question is about configuration, not about programming and was correctly closed.

Comment: The line for network administration questions is a little bit fuzzy, the written guideline states "Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools." [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please don't use other questions that slipped through as justification for your question.

Comment: "*how to connect to EC2 on private subnet. First link (after AWS) is stackoverflow with many comments, answers and upvotes.*" If I type in "how to connect to EC2 on private subnet" (without the quotes) I don't get any SO links at all. And if I append "stackoverflow.com" I get few questions where the first five have a total of six answers between them. as well as 19 comments (that's not a lot). The highest score among the five questions is 1.

Comment: Ok. I am not going to debate or argue here. That is not the intention. I am highlighting a flaw or gap and it is for the administrators to take it for considerations or not. I can tell you this. I have been working on implementing my project on AWS for last 6 months. And almost all (say 80%) of the time - the relevant answer is on SO. And it is on page 1 of google search. Generally below the AWS (Amazon links) itself - which is understantable. It is not one question slipping by.

Comment: @VLAZ - 5th link is SO if you search that (without quotes). At least for me. I cannot send image in comments it seems

Comment: @python25 Comments are not meant to contain information that should be included in the question itself.

Comment: The core of your answer is answered by [ssm](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-port-forwarding-using-aws-system-manager-sessions-manager/), but SSM questions around using it with a GUI tend to perform poorly here on SO, since they almost always require quite a bit of back and forth and discussion, something SO isn't geared well for, hence the closure.

Comment: It's **not about the technology you're using**. It's about the question you're asking. Regardless of the topic, if searching for your question title finds you existing Stack Overflow questions, you should **read them and see if they answer your question** instead of posting a duplicate.

Comment: You guys are trying hard to just prove me wrong rather than investigating. This is surprising for a community as mature as SO. It is NOT a duplicate. I gave an example of the most closely related question. Example is EC2, mine was on RDS. That too about RDS/EC2 with instance endpoint setup.

Comment: Oh no, we investigated all right.  By checking your question to see if it was rightfully closed, which it was.  No one set out to prove you wrong, that just happened to be the outcome of the investigation.

Comment: @python25 If you see a question that is off topic appear to not be closed.  Flag it for closure, via the flag dialog, or bring it up in an area so as to bring attention to it so it can be closed.  It is not justification, as others have said, that can be used for your also-off-topic question.  Contribute to the solution, rather than the problem.

Comment: General rule of thumb: If you don't have code, Stack Overflow is the wrong site. Of course there are conceptual questions, but even those are usually best explained with a bit of code. And if the question is about code but resolves to, "Write the code for me, monkeyboy." Yeah... It's going to be a bad user experience.

Comment: @python25 do you know [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)? This is a sibling SO site which is part of the Stack Exchange Q&A Network. The Stack Exchange Network comprises a collective of thematically specialized Q&As, here's a [list of sites that integrated the network](https://stackexchange.com/sites). In the same way that SO focuses on programming languages and software development, Server Fault focuses on the management of IT systems in a business environment. Perhaps Server Fault is the most appropriate community to receive your question about AWS configuration.

Answer (score 27):

I have closed your question, because it is not about programming problem. You are asking about how to connect and configure your network infrastructure.

From the Help center [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

> 7. Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless
>    they directly involve programming or programming tools.

Answer (score 6):

> How is that possible if only programming questions should be on this site.

When the system is working as intended, that happens **because those AWS questions are programming questions**.

This *does not* mean that *your* AWS question is a programming question, in general. Whether or not a question is "about programming" is *not* determined by the technologies you are using, whether there are other questions on the site that mention the same technologies, whether there is a tag with a bunch of questions and/or a tag wiki about that technology, etc.

Instead, whether or not a question is "about programming" is determined **by the principles described in the help center** article titled [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

A suitable question *must cover at least one of*:

> - a specific **programming problem**
> - a software **algorithm**
> - software tools **commonly used by programmers**

(in the latter case, the consensus understanding is that the tool should be reasonably specific to the act of programming - obviously, we don't take questions about how to e.g. draw circles in Photoshop *unless* you are *scripting* this process, such that you have "a specific programming problem")

*and it must be*

> a practical, answerable problem that is **unique to software development**

*and* it **must *not* be looking for [customer support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745) or anything to do with legal issues** surrounding programming.

In particular, and for avoidance of doubt: Super User exists specifically to take questions about using your computer, even in ways that "ordinary" users might not try, if what you are trying to do is not something specific to the process of developing software (even if it might happen to help you develop software in your particular situation). Server Fault, similarly, takes the analogous questions about network configuration.

In some situations, "configuration" tasks can be considered on topic for Stack Overflow, **depending on the nature of the configuration file**. Specifically, it will depend on whether editing the file "feels like programming". For example, does the creator of the file need to engage in the same kind of logical reasoning that a programmer does? Does the configuration file describe the scripted automation of a process?

---

When the system is *not* working as intended, we get questions remaining open counter to policy. **If you find one, please vote to close it or flag it for closure** (you can start casting flags at 15 reputation). Flagging such questions prioritizes them for consideration by those with close-vote privileges.

If you find yourself trying to point at existing questions in order to justify your own question, you are Doing Stack Overflow Wrong™. It's **not about you** - in particular, it's not about whether you get to post the question you want to post. It's about whether the question you're proposing meets standards. If other questions managed to sneak under the radar, this doesn't justify your question. If we didn't close questions that should have been closed, it's nothing to do with either you or the authors of those questions. It's just an oversight, and you should help us by pointing it out.

Please also keep in mind that Stack Overflow's standards have changed over time. In particular, Super User and Server Fault (and several other offshoots for technical, computer-related topics) didn't exist at the beginning. As a consequence there are many old questions on the site that were well received but would be considered off topic by current standards. Generally, when these are identified, they get a ["historical lock"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts).